# Do assets custodied by a trustee form part of the Bankruptcy Estate if the trustee enters Chapter 11 Bankruptcy

Tags: united-states, trusts-and-estates, limited-liability-company, bankruptcy, securities

I own some securities giving me a beneficial interest in an LLC (let's call it LLC A) which were issued to another LLC (let's call it LLC B) as a custodian and trustee. LLC B has entered Chapter 11 Bankruptcy proceedings in the State of Delaware. Will these securities form part of the Bankruptcy Estate of the trustee and am I considered a Creditor of the trustee?

Additionally, my ownership of the securities makes me a Limited Partner of LLC A. If the securities do form part of the Bankruptcy Estate of LLC B, would I still be considered a Limited Partner of LLC A?

Comment: So, LLC B is the legal owner of LLC A’s shares and you are the beneficial owner? I’m confused because you say that you are a partner of A - beneficial ownership doesn't  generally give you any control.

Answer (score 1):

> Will these securities form part of the Bankruptcy Estate of the
> trustee and am I considered a Creditor of the trustee?

The case law on this subject [is not entirely consistent](https://www.wcslaw.com/accolades/trust-funds-and-property-of-the-estates-in-bankruptcy/).

Some courts have held that the property held in trust is not part of the bankruptcy estate at all, while others have held that it remains part of the bankruptcy estate, but only to the extent of the trustee's legal title, while the beneficial interest of the assets held in trust remain outside the bankruptcy estate.

But Delaware is in the 3rd U.S. Court of Appeals Circuit, so that circuit's case law controls in a bankruptcy case. The controlling case in the 3rd Circuit says that custodial and trust property is not part of the bankruptcy estate at all.  *City of Farrell v. Sharon Steel Corp.*, [41 F.3d 92](https://casetext.com/case/city-of-farrell-v-sharon-steel-corp), 95 (3d Cir. 1994). *See also Bank of Marin v. England*, [385 U.S. 99](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/385/99/) (1966).

Still, it is probably better practice to file the simple and short standard proof of claim form asserting your interest in the property held in trust in clear language (in an attachment to the proof of claim form, if necessary), even though your interest in the bankruptcy estate doesn't fit perfectly within what the proof of claim form contemplates.

The reason that this might be a good idea is just in case someone misrepresents that these assets are owned outright by LLC B (or by someone else), rather than being held in trust for you.

Also, it preserves a jurisdictional deadline for filing claims that could bite you if the case law changes before this bankruptcy case is concluded and you didn't file a proof of claim form by the jurisdictional deadline. There is a heightened risk of a change in the law any time there is a circuit split over an issue important to your case, as there is with respect to this issue.

> my ownership of the securities makes me a Limited Partner of LLC A. If
> the securities do form part of the Bankruptcy Estate of LLC B, would I
> still be considered a Limited Partner of LLC A?

Yes, to the same extent that you were prior to the bankruptcy filing.

**Additional Thoughts**

Bankruptcies of companies like LLC B are very rare. The reason that it occurred should guide how worried you should be. If there were allegations of fraud, you should be very worried. If it was due to some unrelated business line or a personal injury claim or something like that, you needn't be worried. If the problem was unpaid taxes, you should have an intermediate level of worry.

There is a federal government insurance agency, similar to the FDIC, called the [Securities Investor Protection Corporation](https://www.sipc.org/) (SIPC), that protects you from losses if companies like LLC B have absconded with, destroyed, or unlawfully transferred to a third-party, the LLC A interests that you own. If this kind of mischief or negligence crops up in the bankruptcy, you may need to file a claim with the SIPC.